# Picture on article Astronomy template

Tags: tikz-pgf, wrapfigure, aastex

using this template I would like to add, for example on the top right 2 pictures (of my university), I tried with some wrapfig, classical begin{figure}, \include{graphics}, tikz, but none of them worked, maybe this document class is not supposed to have a picture in it but maybe someone has an idea on how to do it anyway, thanks.
https://fr.overleaf.com/latex/templates/astronomy-and-astrophysics-template/ngdddtchkbcg

Comment: Do you want to use this template for private matters? I don't think you should add images to it if you want to use this template to submit a paper to this journal.

Comment: @JasperHabicht yes this is for a school report and I wanted to do something original

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code after `\documentclass{aa}`

```
%************************************ 
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\aa@journalname{%
\raisebox{\baselineskip}{Astronomy \& Astrophysics \qquad  manuscript no. jobname} 
}

\renewcommand*\aa@manuscriptname{%
    \centering
    \hspace{\stretch{1}}\includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth]{example-image-a}\quad\includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth]{example-image-b}\\
    \hspace{\stretch{1}}%
    \copyright ESO \the\year
}

\makeatother
%************************************
```

[image: a]

Comment: Perfect thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: By the way, for the pages after the title page the header has 'A&A proofs: manuscript no. output' do you know how I could change it by adding my name for example ?

Comment: @Michael Add    \renewcommand*\aa@textidlineempty{ My Name}  before `\makeatother`

Comment: Once again it works without any problem, thanks again, are you used to this format ?

Comment: @Michael Not especially. I just read the TeX code of `aa.cls`. Good luck with your report!

Comment: Ok wow impression I tried to read it but those commands were not looking very friendly to me , thank you very much!